# Name of animation like coverflow

Tags: animation, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that can reproduce the animation on the picture.

When I click on "next" in the popup, the first page fades out and the page behind goes on the top. I think it's a kind of coverflow but I can't find anything from this appellation.

Do you know the specific name for that? I need a plugin before hardcoding the complete animation.

[image: Example]

The link: http://www.sponseasy.com/

Comment: I'd call it a stacked coverflow.

Comment: The most common appellation today is carousel instead of coverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Apple time machine effect

Here you go CSS3 example
http://forrst.com/posts/CSS3_Time_Machine-5Yr